# Can I customize compiled css location inside head tag?

Tags: meteor

Meteor compiles the css files into one css file and inserts it as first child of  head element in html.

```
<head>
  <!-- meteor inserts my concatenated css file from client folder here -->
  <title>page</title>
  <link href="/sometheme/theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- other css files here -->
</head>
```

I don't want to create a package for the theme assets I am using. I just want to use them directly in the html like above and I want to develop my css in the client folder with a preprocessor.

How can I get meteor to inject the generated css as last element of head rather than first which is default?

Thanks

**EDIT**:

To clarify further, I want meteor to inject the compiled css as shown below. I could manipulate the DOM and move that link after DOM is ready but it's a hack. Is there an API to configure this?

```
<head>
  <title>page</title>
  <link href="/sometheme/theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- other css files here -->
  <!-- I WANT METEOR TO INJECT COMPILED CSS HERE -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" class="__meteor-css__" href="/main.css?da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709">
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@import url;` declaration on top of your css file.

main.css

```
@import '/sometheme/theme.css';

body {

}
```

This will load /public/sometheme/theme.css before your css

Comment: @import will create additional http requests in css file. Not ideal. I think I'll have to use a build tool like grunt, gulp, etc. this done. Frustrating.... :/

Answer (score 0):

Just place your css theme and meteor will concatenate it into existing css. Meteor have a special way with [file order](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp):

1. HTML template files are always loaded before everything else
2. Files beginning with main. are loaded last
3. Files inside any lib/ directory are loaded next
4. Files with deeper paths are loaded next
5. Files are then loaded in alphabetical order of the entire path

To achieve your goal, just make sure you the your css is deeper than the theme folder and be aware with the alphabetical ordering

Edit:

If you want to load file from /public, just place `<head></head>` in one of html file (e.g.: app.html) and reference your stylesheet there.

app.html:

```
<head>
  <link href="/sometheme/theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

It will refer /public/sometheme/theme.css

Comment: place my css theme where?

Comment: Place it in client/stylesheets folder. The trick is to get the right ordering. Edited my answer.

Comment: Theme folder has javascript, font, css, less and other files. If I put the folder in client, meteor will process (concat, etc) them which I don't want it. I also don't want to rename and change anything in the theme folder. That is why I put them into the public folder. Your file prioritization explanation applies to folders in non public folders. So, I only need to figure out if I can get meteor to inject compiled css as last link element in head.

Comment: In that case, you just need to place <head></head> in one of your html file

Comment: You can place <head></head> in any .html file you have (outside <template><template>). See my edited answer.

Comment: I already load the theme css in the head. Please read the question again.

Comment: Sorry I misread your question. Another way to achieve your goal is place your theme in /public and use `@import url;` declaration on top of your css.